# SSRS - Popup Message

Tags: reporting-services, messagebox

Is it possible to create a pop-up message in SSRS. For example, can I create an action on an image that will show a message box with some additional information?

Comment: You can either use hover text or an action that contains javascript.  Otherwise, you can probably write some custom code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm not looking to implement a tooltip. Could you provide some guidance how I would take the javascript / custom code route.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155798%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: Here is a good resource for the javascript: http://experiencingmsbi.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-javascript-in-ssrs.html

Answer (score 0):

On the action of the image you can make a textbox or rectangle visible wit a message in it.